# Let $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} \le 1 \}$, Evaluate the $\iint_D x^2 dA$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Okay so I know the idea of solving these types of problems, but what I'm concerned about is when we have to use a change of variable formula and when not to... specifically, for this example we have to:

Let $u = \frac x2$ and $w = \frac y3$, so $x = 2u$ and $y = 3w$, plugging this into the jacobian matrix we get 6 as the determinant.

Then we plug in $x = 2u$ into the equation, $x^2$, multiplied by the determinant which is absolute value of $6 \text{ dudw}$.

I though all we needed to do was get the domain in polar coordinates, $(r,\theta)$ and then sub $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$, set up the integral for the equation following $r \text{drd}\theta$ and solve?

Comment: Is it because we don't have a proper radius, as the shape is an ellipse? So we need to 'make' it into a unit circle I guess so we get a proper radius?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use elliptic coordinates immediatelly, which are nothing else but a little bit modified polar coordinates. Write $x=2r \cos \theta$ and $y = 3r \cos \theta$ and the Jacobian will be $6r$ and $0 \le r \le 1$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$

In fact what you did is exactly this, but in an explicit form. The region $D$ is an ellipse. The linear transformation $x=2u$ and $y=3v$ in fact streches it into a circle. Then you can use the polar coordinates to solve the integral. The first way does the two steps at once.

Comment: why would r be bounded between 0 and 1 tho, the ellipse doesn't have a radius of 1. More importantly though - i was just wondering why in some cases we have to solve the jacobian matrix to get a numerical value THEN convert to polar aside from other examples where we could just convert to polar, knowing the jacobian (which is r, or p^2sinphi) etc

Comment: @Mathguy substituting into the equation might give you a clue for the range of r. You will get $r^2 \le 1$. For the other question I'm not sure what are you asking, but I will try to answer. Polar coordinates work only when we have circle as our region. In fact we're always calculating the Jacobian, but in the case of polar coordinates it's value is well-known so we can skip those calculations. Getting a numerical value corresponds to a linear transformation. Stretching the ellipse is such a transformation and that's why we multiply by the Jacobian. In general you can have a non-numerical valu

Comment: Yes that makes sense. To clarify one point - multiplying by the jacobian is responsible for 'stretching the ellipse to a circle'? For example if we have cases where it's a circle, we can just skip the jacobian because we would get 'r', so rdrdtheta, but for non-circular shapes we multiply by the jacobian?

Comment: @Mathguy We don't skip the Jacobian, the Jacobian is r in that case. In fact the Jacobian is the stretching factor. It's the ratio of the old region and the new region after the change of variables. Sometimes it's a constant value, sometimes it depends on the variables